# Saving record in RavenDb with F# adding extra Id column

Tags: f#, ravendb

When I save a new F# Record, I'm getting an extra column called `Id@` in the RavenDb document, and it shows up when I load or view the object in code; it's even being converted to JSON through my F# API.

Here is my F# record type:

```
type Campaign = { mutable Id : string; name : string; description : string }
```

I'm not doing anything very exciting to save it:

```
let save c : Campaign =
    use session = store.OpenSession()
    session.Store(c)
    session.SaveChanges()
    c
```

Saving a new instance of a record creates a document with the Id of `campaigns/289`. Here is the full value of the document in RavenDb:

```
{
    "Id@": "campaigns/289",
    "name": "Recreating Id bug",
    "description": "Hello StackOverflow!"
}
```

Now, when I used this same database (and document) in C#, I didn't get the extra `Id@` value. This is what a record looks like when I saved it in C#:

```
{
    "Description": "Hello StackOverflow!",
    "Name": "Look this worked fine",
}
```

(Aside - "name" vs "Name" means I have 2 name columns in my document. I understand that problem, at least).

So my question is: **How do I get rid of the extra `Id@` property being created when I save an F# record in RavenDb?**

Comment: Wait, why is that column "extra"? I can clearly see it right there in your `Campaign` record definition.

Comment: Because the C# object definition also has an `Id` property, but it doesn't show up as a document value - it's the value used to access the document. The document created with F# has both the Id used to look up the specific database record, and a JSON value _in_ the document called `Id@`; the C# version doesn't have the "extra" JSON value in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of... well, you can't quite call them "bugs", so let's say "non-straightforward features" in both F# compiler and RavenDb.

The F# compiler generates a `public` backing field for the `Id` record field. This field is named `Id@` (a standard pattern for all F# backing fields), and it's `public`, because the record field is mutable. For immutable record fields, backing fields will be `internal`. Why it needs to generate a public backing field for mutable record fields, I don't know.

Now, RavenDb, when generating the schema, apparently looks at both properties *and* fields. This is a bit non-standard. The usual practice is to consider only properties. But alas, Raven picks up the public field named `Id@`, and makes it part of the schema.

You can combat this problem in two ways:

**First**, you could make the `Id` field immutable. I'm not sure whether that would work for you or RavenDb. Perhaps not, since the `Id` is probably generated on insert.

**Second**, you could declare your `Campaign` not as an F# record, but as a true class:

```
type Campaign( id: int, name: string, description: string ) = 
    member val Id = id with get, set
    member val name = name
    member val description = description
```

This way, all backing fields stay internal and no confusion will arise. The drawback is that you have to write every field twice: first as constructor argument, then as class member.

Comment: Removing the `mutable` from `Id` makes the records unable to load the Ids from Raven, both for saving a new object _and_ for even loading an existing one. I will look into the class option, but I may also explore other document DBs and see if one plays nicer with F#. Thank you for the in-depth explanation, you really helped explain the issue!

Comment: Without the `mutable`, you might run into this problem where the Id doesn't get populated with the generated value on save. If you never need to know the Id of a just-inserted record, you're fine.

Answer (score 6):

As noted by Fyodor, this is caused by how F# generates a backing field when you create a record type.  The default contract resolver for RavenDB serializes that backing field instead of the public property.

[You can change the default contract resolver in ravendb.](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/configuration/conventions/request-handling)  It will look something like this if you want to use the Newtonsoft Json.Net:

```
DocumentStore.Conventions.JsonContractResolver <- new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

There is an explanation for why this works [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/03/19/posting-json-to-an-f-web-api/) (see the section titled: "The explanation").  Briefly, the Newtonsoft library uses the public properties of the type instead of the private backing fields.

I also recommend, instead of having the `mutable` property on the `Id`, you can put the `[<CLIMutable>]` attribute on the type itself like:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Campaign = { Id : string; name : string; description : string }
```

This makes it so libraries can mutate the values while preventing it in your code.